# Is it good practice to give html elements id attributes that are only to be used for testing purposes?

Tags: html, css, unit-testing, testing, selenium

Suppose I have a form like so:

```
<form action="/foo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

In my case, there is no need for me to give any of the input tags an "id" attribute. It isn't styled via CSS, there is no javascript referencing it, etc... However, there is a QA department that would love it if it had a hardcoded "id" such as "login-button" so that their automated test would stay stable.

**CONS** As the developer a am highly skeptical about adding id attributes that serve no functional purpose.

- I think it clutters the code.
- Confuses future developers looking at
  it.
- Binds us to whatever testing tool is being used at the time.
- Binds us to code outside of the product's codebase.
- Starts down a slippery slope of the code knowing something about how it will be tested and vice-versa.

**PROS**:
From the QA perspective, I can certainly sympathize that this would:

- make their work easier.
- provide stability (in the short term)

Can I get some help expanding on the Pros/Cons lists I have started here?

Comment: Do you mean an id of the form itself? Or the inputs within? (rhetoric I guess. I can see what you mean) If the form itself I think just because it is standard. Perhaps it will allow it to "validate" as proper html, if that's at all important. I agree that adding an id to every element is foolish. That would make no sense

Comment: Perhaps the form will have an id, but only because it is "standard" (I think that is debatable as well though). I think more generally what they are asking for is id's on anything they are writing the test to interact with.

Comment: No labels on those inputs? Perhaps you just excluded them for brevity?

Comment: @steveax Correct. That isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Labels are relevant to the question, because for WAI and usability reasons, input fields should have labels associated with `label` markup, and the natural way for this uses `id` attributes on the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The biggest insight  I think is that it's ok to add id's for testing.. We should document them and allow test writers to use them when/if they need. Win-win.

Answer (score 5):

One important **functional** reason to include `id` attributes on form inputs is so that you can explicitly associate the corresponding `label` elements with the inputs:

```
<form action="/foo" method="POST">
    <label for="username">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</form>
```

This is important for accessibility and usability. Screen reader users rely on this association so that they know what input they are typing into. There's also a **huge** usability difference when the labels are properly associated (user can click on the label to set the focus to the associated input). This is really apparent with `checkbox` and `radio` inputs.

[Fiddle with example of both on checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Nn7/). *(Note how much easier it is to click on the label rather than the input itself)*

As for your opposition... I'm not sure how adding `id` attributes does any of the "cons" you state. Clutter? nope, valid usable code. Confusing? nope, id's and properly associated labels would be the first thing I'd add if I saw that code. Binds you to a test tool and outside code? how exactly? The fact that it would make your testing crew's life easier is just icing on the cake.

Comment: Actually you can surround the input with a label and still meet accessibility requirements, e.g.
    `<label>User Name<input type="text" name="username"></label>`

Answer (score 4):

Your first 2 Cons are valid, but I disagree with the last 3.

You could take the stance that you will provide logical element Id's for your testers, but they are responsible for utilizing them with whatever testing tools etc... that they use. This means that you are test/tool agnostic, you just provide the Id's for testing use without necessarily knowing exactly how they will be used.

Adding Id's like this is fairly standard practice for a lot of web apps today.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, their testing tool should fill in the fields based on their name attributes and the form's action attribute if there are multiple forms on the page. These are guaranteed to be as stable as the part of the server answering the POST request.

Ids, field ordering, and other attributes might change due to front-end reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For me it depends. It depends on if the elements can be easily and reliably found without the ID.

In your example, yes, so adding the ID isn't a waste but just isn't necessary. However that's all that is, an example.

In a lot of web pages, as they become more complex and complicated, ID's become your friend, because without it you will need to look at other ways of finding elements.

Especially in the Selenium world, when you come across this problem, you generally turn to CSS and/or XPath selectors.

Other selectors are not bad things, but they can quite slow in older browsers, if you support them.

Comment: Why would adding `id` attributes slow older browsers?